# How to output to file from cassandra client?

Tags: cassandra

I want to save result of list command into file.
How can I do it from cassandra-cli?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Save the commands you'd type into a file to be used as a script, then invoke cli:

```
cassandra-cli <commands.txt >listing.txt
```

Answer (score 3):

For me using a pipe for input did not work. I used the *--file* argument of cassandra-cli. For example:

```
cassandra-cli --file commands.txt > listing.txt
```